# Unable to plot due to size of x and y arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a number of plots of temperature (te) versus time (t), where for each plot, a different timestep (dt) is used to calculate the temperature. [image: original plot]. Initially my code ran fine and I produced the plot shown (the plot is made up of a number of plots, more visible when zoomed in). However after making an adjustment to my values for dt_values I have not been able to run the code, and am getting the 'x and y must have same first dimension' error message but I cannot see why.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = 0.024 #cooling rate per minute
te_init = 90.0

te_surr = 17

dt_values = [0.05, 0.025, 0.01, 0.005, 0.001]

for j in dt_values:
    t = np.arange(0,100,j)
    te = np.zeros(len(t))
    te[0] = te_init 

    def f(te):
        y = -r*(te - te_surr) # y is the derivative
        return y
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        te[i] = te[i-1] + f(te[i-1])*j
        plt.plot(t, te[i], label = j)
        plt.xlabel('Time, [min]')
        plt.ylabel('Temperature, [C]')
        plt.title('Adaptive Time Steps')
        plt.legend(loc=4)
```

Comment: `t` has length `j`, while `te[i]` is a single number. For `j != 1` (which is mostly the case), it does not make sense to plot a list of `j` values versus a single number. This is what the error tells you.

Comment: The problem is, when I try to plot t verus te, it goes into 'not responding'. So I thought maybe I should be plotting t versus te[i]

Comment: The problem with your question is a bit, that it is not clear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I am looking to produce a series of plots of temperature (te) versus time (t). And for each of these plots a different time step (dt) is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot outside the loop, which populates the temperature array. Then `plt.plot(t, te)` is working as expected.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = 0.024 #cooling rate per minute
te_init = 90.0
te_surr = 17

def f(te):
    return -r*(te - te_surr) # the derivative

dt_values = [20, 5, 1, 0.1, 0.05]

for dt in dt_values:
    t = np.arange(0,100,dt)
    te = np.zeros(len(t))
    te[0] = te_init 

    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        te[i] = te[i-1] + f(te[i-1])*dt

    plt.plot(t, te, label = dt)

plt.xlabel('Time, [min]')
plt.ylabel('Temperature, [C]')
plt.title('Adaptive Time Steps')
plt.legend(loc=4, title="Timestep [min]")

plt.show()
```

[image]